# Timer from previous push of view controller is still running

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

I have a navigation controller which I push a further view controller into when needed. This pushed view controller has a function fired off every minute using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay.

All this works fine but I've noticed that the function is still firing off long after having tapped < Back out of the pushed view controller.

I can see why this is happening- I'm not telling the pushed view controller to cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget upon exit. But since viewDidUnload is no longer supported and dealloc similarly doesn't seem to be called when tapping < Back, can anyone suggest the best way to go about performing this at the correct time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `- (void)viewWillDisappear:`

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two entry points:

- `viewWillDisappear:`, invoked when the view is about to disappear
- `viewDidDisappear:`, invoked when the view has disappeared